# Drag and drop on script not behaving properly

Tags: python

So, I made this quick python script that takes a file name and fixes it up for use on linux.

```
import os
import sys

args = sys.argv

file = args[1].split('\\')
file = file[len(file)-1]

newfile = ''

for char in file:
    if char.isupper():
        newfile += '_' + char.lower()
    elif not char.isalnum() and char != '.':
        newfile += '_'
    else:
        newfile += char

newfile = newfile.lstrip('_')
os.rename(args[1],newfile)
```

It does its job properly, but if you drag the file on top if it, it won't rename the file. I debugged with some print statements and it does receive the file as an arg if you drag and drop it, but it won't rename it. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: At request, adding some OS details.

Using Windows 7, SP1 64 bit, Ultimate Edition
Using Python 2.7 64 bit

Comment: I think it may not be able to change the file  name since it's in "use" (when you drag the file on top)

Comment: @MohammadS. That does make sense, but why would it be in "use" when dropped, but not when given as a command line option. The script opens both of them the same. Just some weird idiosyncrasy with Windows and or Python?

Comment: I'm not able to answer the question beyond speculation (since I'm not near my computer), but I'll upvote this.  It's an interesting issue.  You should add which exact OS you're testing in and provide some images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now is more brief and simple.

```
import os
import sys

args = sys.argv
path = "\\".join(args[1].split('\\')[:-1])
file_name = args[1].split("\\")[-1]

file_name = file_name.lower()
file_name = file_name.replace(' ','_')

file_name = path+'\\'+file_name
os.rename(args[1],file_name)
```

Comment: Didn't change anything. The reserved file name was not actually an issue. The script itself works... just not for drag and drop.

Comment: So did I, and it didn't.

Comment: Hmm, that did seem to fix it, it may not necessarily be the reserved word, it may just be that the command line has some better cases for handling renaming open files.